# Inner product and Integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, differential-geometry, curves, arc-length

I was reading a proof that claims that the length of a curve $\alpha:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ which is denoted by $l(\alpha)$ satisfies $l(\alpha)\geq|\alpha(a)-\alpha(b)|$ .
It starts by

$\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)=\int_a^b\alpha'(t)dt$ and then by applying the inner product with $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)$ at this equality we have:

$$|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)|^2=\int_a^b\bigl\langle\alpha'(t),\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\bigr\rangle dt$$
and then it continues with the proof.

My doubt is with this implication. The step $$|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)|^2=\left\langle\int_a^b\alpha'(t) dt,\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\right\rangle$$
is missing, but why $$\left\langle\int_a^b\alpha'(t) dt,\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\right\rangle=\int_a^b\bigl\langle\alpha'(t),\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\bigr\rangle dt?$$ Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because\begin{align}\bigl\|\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\bigr\|^2&=\bigl\langle\alpha(b)-\alpha(a),\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\bigr\rangle\\&=\left\langle\int_a^b\alpha'(t)\,\mathrm dt,\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\right\rangle\\&=\int_a^b\bigl\langle\alpha'(t),\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\bigr\rangle\,\mathrm dt.\end{align}

Comment: My doubt is in the last equality. Why is $\langle\int_a^b\alpha'(t) dt,\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\rangle$ equal to $\int_a^b\langle\alpha'(t),\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\rangle dt$? Is it because in the LHS $\int_a^b\alpha'(t) dt$ can be understood as a sum of vectors?

Comment: The inner product here is a finite sum implicitely. So it is just linearity of the integration operation.

Comment: If $\alpha'(t)=\bigl(x_1(t),\ldots,x_n(t)\bigr)$ and $\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)=(y_1,\ldots,y_n)$, then\begin{align}\left\langle\int_a^b\alpha'(t)\,\mathrm dt,\alpha(b)-\alpha(a)\right\rangle&=\left\langle\left(\int_a^bx_1(t)\,\mathrm dt,\ldots,\int_a^bx_n(t)\,\mathrm dt\right),(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\right\rangle\\&=\left(\int_a^bx_1(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)y_1+\cdots+\left(\int_a^bx_n(t)\,\mathrm dt\right)y_n\\&=\int_a^bx_1(t)y_1+x_2(t)y_2+\cdots+x_n(t)y_n\,\mathrm dt\\&=\int_a^b\bigl\langle\bigl(x_1(t),\ldots,x_n(t)\bigr),(y_1,\ldots,y_n)\bigr\rangle\,\mathrm dt\end{align}